# Fitting data to weibull distribution

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, weibull

I have a set of integer values, and I want to set them to Weibull distribution and get the best fit parameters. Then I draw the histogram of data together with the pdf of Weibull distribution, using the best fit parameters. This is the code I used.

```
from jtlHandler import *
import warnings
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def get_pdf(latencies):

    a = np.array(latencies)
    ag = st.gaussian_kde(a)
    ak = np.linspace(np.min(a), np.max(a), len(a))
    agv = ag(ak)
    plt.plot(ak,agv)
    plt.show()
    return (ak,agv)

def fit_to_distribution(distribution, data):
    params = distribution.fit(data)
    # Return MLEs for shape (if applicable), location, and scale parameters from data.
    #
    # MLE stands for Maximum Likelihood Estimate. Starting estimates for the fit are given by input arguments; for any arguments not provided with starting estimates, self._fitstart(data) is called to generate such.

    return params

def make_distribution_pdf(dist, params, end):
    arg = params[:-2]
    loc = params[-2]
    scale = params[-1]

    # Build PDF and turn into pandas Series
    x = np.linspace(0, end, end)
    y = dist.pdf(x, loc=loc, scale=scale, *arg)
    pdf = pd.Series(y, x)

    return pdf


latencies = getLatencyList("filename")

latencies = latencies[int(9*(len(latencies)/10)):len(latencies)]
data = pd.Series(latencies)

params = fit_to_distribution(st.weibull_max, data)
print("Parameters for the fit: "+str(params))



# Make PDF
pdf = make_distribution_pdf(st.weibull_max, params, max(latencies))

# Display
plt.figure()
ax = pdf.plot(lw=2, label='PDF', legend=True)
data.plot(kind='hist', bins=200, normed=True, alpha=0.5, label='Data', 
legend=True, ax=ax)

ax.set_title('Weibull distribution')
ax.set_xlabel('Latnecy')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')

plt.savefig("image.png")
```

This is the resulting figure.
[image]

As it is seen, the Weibull approximation is not simmilar to the original distribution of data.

How can I get the best Weibull approximation to my data?

Comment: Based on the shape of the histogram, it looks like you should be using `weibull_min`, not `weibull_max`.

Comment: I don't know about this example. Some general advice. (1) Separate the parameter estimation from the plotting and debug each one. (2) What are the parameter estimates you are getting? Are they reasonable given the data? What if you construct a data set for which you know the correct estimates a priori? e.g. generate random data from a distribution with specific parameters. (3) About plotting, do you get a result which is plausible given the parameters? What if you substitute a distribution with known parameters? Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fit a data set (set of numbers) to any distribution using the following two methods.

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import math
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
from scipy.stats._continuous_distns import _distn_names
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def fit_to_distribution(distribution, latency_values):
    distribution = getattr(st, distribution)
    params = distribution.fit(latency_values)

    return params


def make_distribution_pdf(distribution, latency_list):
    distribution = getattr(st, distribution)
    params = distribution.fit(latency_list)

    arg = params[:-2]
    loc = params[-2]
    scale = params[-1]
    x = np.linspace(min(latency_list), max(latency_list), 10000)
    y = distribution.pdf(x, loc=loc, scale=scale, *arg)
    return x, y
```